# What is the future of weblogic portal developer?

Tags: weblogic

Now that Oracle have come up with a webcenter which is also a portal like product.

I understand that the weblogic portal support will be until 2017.

As a developer using this product, how should i move on from here?

Should i start developing on webcentre and how togo about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Web Center 11 is quite different from WLPortal. It's a totally new concept involving Spaces, Fusion Middleware and JDeveloper extensions to build the portal.

> As a developer using this product, how
>   should i move on from here?

Weblogic Portal will eventually stop getting used for new projects, so you will be better off picking up either **Oracle Web Center** or use the portal concepts you have and get into **Liferay** or **JBoss GateIn**. The second is what I *personally* suggest, so your resume has a wider set of options for the future.

> Should i start developing on webcentre
>   and how togo about it?

Well, download the [JDeveloper 11.1.1.4 with OWC extensions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/webcenter/downloads/index.html) and start digging in.

**More Links:**

http://www.yonaweb.be/new_features_webcenter_11114_0