# Oracle weblogic portal

Tags: weblogic

My question may be basic,

What is 'Oracle Weblogic Portal'? Is that a product from Oracle or does it mean a web portal (using J2EE) developed as Weblogic as application server?

Comment: See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918462/what-is-the-future-of-weblogic-portal-developer/5919349#5919349 and edit your question if you need more info. Weblogic Portal is the old BEA product which will be EOL soon. It does NOT mean any web portal which runs on Weblogic server

Comment: Thanks JoseK, after further reading i understand about Weblogic Portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From that product's homepage at oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic-portal/overview/index.html)

> Oracle WebLogic Portal, **formerly BEA WebLogic Portal**, is the best-of-breed portal framework for creating highly interactive composite applications in a SOA environment...

It is now an Oracle product, since [Oracle bought BEA Systems](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/015680_EN) quite a while ago.

Comment: +1 Also, I think that they will phase out the "Weblogic" part in the product, so that future releases will be just "Oracle Portal". I think this naming convention started with 11g.

Comment: Mat, Thanks for your reply. Before posting my question, i read that information in that page. I couldn't understand much. Would you mind providing more explanation or any useful links?